# VB6: Runtime Error '13': Type Mismatch when setting and int with an int

Tags: winapi, vb6

I'm not new to VB6 programming, but I'm not a master at it either. Hopefully someone can help me out with a question that I have concerning a Type Mismatch error that I'm receiving from trying to set an int variable with a int returned from a function.

The integer that I'm trying to set is defined as:

```
Global AICROSSDOCKStatus As Integer
```

Now when I try to make this call I get the Runtime Error 13

```
AICROSSDOCKStatus = ProcessQuery(iocode, pb, AICROSSDOCBOLFN, "")
```

I've stepped through debugging the program line for line. The ProcessQuery function gets and returns the expected integer, but when the assignment is to be made to the AICROSSDOCKStatus it fails.

On a side note, I've also tried doing a CInt() to the ProcessQuery with the same result.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I may be able to try?

Edit:
Here is the definition of ProcessQuery

```
Function ProcessQuery(icode As Integer, pb As ADODB.Recordset, TableName As String, sql$) As Integer
```

Edit 2:  I couldn't tell you why this was done in this manner. I inherited the code base. Yikes...

```
Function ProcessQuery(icode As Integer, pb As ADODB.Recordset, TableName As String, sql$) As Integer
    ProcessQuery = ProcessQuery1(icode, pb, TableName, sql$)
End Function
```

```
Function ProcessQuery1(icode As Integer, pb As ADODB.Recordset, TableName As String, sql$) As Integer
''THIS IS THE ORIGINAL SQL CALL ROUTINE!
Dim STATUS As Integer
On Error GoTo ProcessSQLError

STATUS = 0
Select Case icode
   Case BCLOSE
        If pb.State  0 Then
            pb.Close
        End If
        Set pb = Nothing
        STATUS = 3
    Case BOPEN
        STATUS = 9
        Set pb = New ADODB.Recordset
    Case BOPENRO
        STATUS = 9
        Set pb = New ADODB.Recordset
    Case BGETEQUAL, BGETEQUAL + S_NOWAIT_LOCK, BGETGREATEROREQUAL, BGETGREATEROREQUAL + S_NOWAIT_LOCK
        If pb.State  0 Then
            pb.Close
            ''Set pb = Nothing
            ''Set pb = New ADODB.Recordset
        End If
        pb.Open sql$, MISCO_SQL_DB, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        If Not pb.EOF Then
            pb.MoveFirst
        Else
            STATUS = 9
        End If
    Case BGET_LE, BGET_LE + S_NOWAIT_LOCK
        If pb.State  0 Then
            pb.Close
        End If
        pb.Open sql$, MISCO_SQL_DB, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        If Not pb.BOF Then
            pb.MoveLast

        Else
            STATUS = 9
        End If
    Case BGETFIRST, BGETFIRST + S_NOWAIT_LOCK
        If pb.State  0 Then pb.Close
        sql = "select * from " + TableName
        If InStr(1, gblOrderBy, "ORDER BY") > 0 Then
            sql = sql + gblOrderBy
        Else
            sql = sql + " ORDER BY " + gblOrderBy
        End If

        gblOrderBy = ""
        pb.Open sql$, MISCO_SQL_DB, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        If Not pb.EOF Then
                                                        pb.MoveFirst
        End If
    Case BGETLAST, BGETLAST + S_NOWAIT_LOCK
        If pb.State  0 Then
            pb.Close
        End If
        sql = "select * from " + TableName
        If InStr(1, gblOrderBy, "ORDER BY") > 0 Then
            sql = sql + gblOrderBy
        Else
            sql = sql + " ORDER BY " + gblOrderBy
        End If
        gblOrderBy = ""
        pb.Open sql$, MISCO_SQL_DB, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        If Not pb.EOF Then
            pb.MoveFirst
            pb.MoveLast
        End If
    Case BGETNEXT, BGETNEXT + S_NOWAIT_LOCK:            pb.MoveNext
    Case BGETPREVIOUS, BGETPREVIOUS + S_NOWAIT_LOCK:    pb.MovePrevious
    Case B_UNLOCK
        ''need to add code here
    Case BINSERT
        If pb.State = 0 Then
            pb.Open TableName, MISCO_SQL_DB, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        End If
    Case BDELETE
        STATUS = 8
        pb.Delete
    Case Else
        STATUS = 1
        MsgBox "STOP: UNDEFINDED PROCEDURE" + Str$(icode)
End Select
If STATUS = 0 Then
    If pb.EOF Or pb.BOF Then STATUS = 9
End If

ProcessQuery1 = STATUS
Exit Function

ProcessSQLError:
    MsgBox TableName + ": " + Error(Err), vbCritical, "Error "
    ProcessQuery1 = 9

End Function
```

Comment: Could you post the definition of ProcessQuery?

Comment: Could you post the full code of ProcessQuery rather than just the signature?

Comment: Wow. Some people code AS IF the maintenance programmer was a violent psychopath who knows where they live. Other people write code that turns any maintainer INTO a violent psychopath. ProcessQuery1 is an product of the second school.

Comment: Introducing Msgbox: Error-handling the EASY way! After all, Err.Raise and error handlers are just...too complicated. You need your errors now and need them to be *in your face!!* BAM! It's `vbCritical` that you adopt this new error-handling "best practice" today!! (**Note** : Actual results may vary. Use of MsgBox as an error-handling strategy may actually lead to increased debugging time, more frustration, higher cholesterol, and hair loss. In rare caes, blindness caused from gouging of eyes with eating utensils such as spoons may also occur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the fact that it was having trouble with the returns from a function but the parameters that were being passed by reference. I needed a Recordset(pb) to pass by reference, but I had declared (pb) as a Record.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't say I know what's breaking, but here's a possible debugging step: Assign a locally defined integer first, then assign AICROSSDOCKStatus to the local int. If the run-time err 13 happens at the first assignment, something REALLY weird is going on - if it happens at the second, then you might want to see if any of your global variables are arrays that you might be overrunning bounds on.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see if the value turns out to be an int,

```
msgbox ProcessQuery(iocode, pb, AICROSSDOCBOLFN, "")
```

I am sure it won't be an int & that is the result it is failing. My guess is that, it will have come characters which makes it a non-numeric value.

You can try `IsNumeric()` function on the results to check, if it is a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an intermediate Variant which should take any kind of type from your function.  It should at least allow you to investigate the real type of the return value.

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you the name of the type your function is actually returning:

```
MsgBox TypeName(ProcessQuery(...))
```

Confining the ProcessQuery() function to int might be helpful in any case, to prevent such errors right from the start:

```
Function ProcessQuery(whatever arguments) As Integer
  ''// ...
End Function
```

Comment: When I try this in ProcessQuery on the ProcessQuery1 I get the expected 'Integer'. When I try TypeName(ProcessQuery(...)) I get the error.

Comment: Then I guess the error occurs *within* ProcessQuery1(). Uncomment the "On Error Goto" statement to see where it is. By the way, the function ProcessQuery1() is... quite a mess, to put it mildly. The Type Mismatch is not at all the only problem it has.

Comment: You're not kidding about it having problems.

It made it through ProcessQuery1, it has the error when the 'End Function' is reached in ProcessQuery.

Comment: Since ProcessQuery() and ProcessQuery1() seem to have the exact same signatures... Can you for the fun of it call ProcessQuery1() directly in your code?

Comment: So the error *does* in fact occur within the ProcessQuery1() function. Did you comment out the "On Error" statement? Strinc concatenation is done with the "&" operator in VB, not with "+". Maybe it's that ("sql = "select * from " + etc. etc.").

Comment: Tried changing it around to take care of that. I'm running this with the following params (BOPEN, <RecordSet>, <String>, ""). So it _should_ just goto BOPEN set the status to 9 give me a new RecordSet and return the integer. All the other cases work fine in returning the correct value.

Comment: Hm. By definition your functions cannot return anything but an Integer. It is just impossible that they don't. The assignment error must be inside the function body. Use the debugger to step through the function line by line if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unusual for an API to return a VB6 Integer, which is a 16-bit quantity. Fairly often, someone translating a C function prototype will confuse a c "int" with a VB6 Integer, when the equivalent is really a Long in VB6.